# Frontier & Substrate

Tags: evm, frontier, fee

Hello we are using frontier, and we would like to remove gas fees for all evm transactons, I tried many things, but didn't achieve..
I still need to pass gas when I sign and send a transaction :

```
await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
            data: ERC20_BYTECODES,
            gasPrice: 1,
            gas: 118196,
            value: 0,
        }, newAccountPrivateKey)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting these in your runtime's `lib.rs`:

```
parameter_types! {
  pub DefaultBaseFeePerGas: U256 = U256::zero();
  pub DefaultElasticity: Permill = Permill::zero();
}

pub struct BaseFeeThreshold;

impl pallet_base_fee::BaseFeeThreshold for BaseFeeThreshold {
  fn lower() -> Permill { Permill::zero() }
  fn ideal() -> Permill { Permill::zero() }
  fn upper() -> Permill { Permill::zero() }
}
```

Be aware that this can lead your chain to DoS attack.

Comment: I tried but, I still get an outOfGas error, thank you.

Comment: It seems that the `eth_estimateGas` is not returning the proper amount of gas needed, have you tried to build your frontier with `cargo b -r --features=rpc-binary-search-estimate`? A heads up that what I recommended here is an approach to not charge for a txn but the gas will still be there.

Comment: I dont have rpc-binary-search-estimate feature. I will check what eth_estimateGas return.

Comment: eth_estimateGas should return 0 ?

Comment: I forced eth_estimateGas to return 0, but I still have outOfGas error

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Oh, you can not do that...the EVM still needs a gas amount to perform its work load.